# Creating a list from size

Tags: java

I know this is easy and can be done with 2 lines of code, but i am curious to know if there exists any such function
i have a int which tell me the size of list and i need to create a list say

```
List<Integer> intList;
```

i can create this by easily iterating through the size something like

```
for(int i=1 ; i <= size; i++)  // started with 1 as i want it from 1
{
  fill list
}
```

but i was just thinking as if there exists any such methods either in Collection API or Apache common
where i can pass the size to get a List with given size

**Edit**

May i was not able to put question in proper way, i want to get filled my list say 
if size=4 than i was thinking abt something

```
Integer=1
Integer=2
Integer=3
Integer=4
```

and not an empty list with size 4

i know question do not make much sense, but still its better to clear your questions

Comment: What should the list contain in the end? If you just want a list of a given size initialized you can simply use an Array.

Comment: A `List` automatically grows as you add elements to it. You do not need to specify the size at the moment you create the list. Just create an empty list and add elements to it.

Comment: Declaring an inital size has a positive influence on speed, so it's not useless

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No

The two-liner you're currently using is already optimal.

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that List is an interface class and you can't create instances of an interface class. So before you want to construct it you need to know what kind of List you want to create. For the moment let's assume you want an ArrayList. From this moment on you can simply use the correct constructor to initialize your list e.g.

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
```

Which constructs an ArrayList of initial capacity 10.

For other kinds of list you can check the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

To fill the list with initial data you can do something like this:

```
int[] myArray = new int[]{ 58,63,67,72,70,63,62,63 };
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(myArray );
```

Comment: No, this creates an `ArrayList` with an initial **capacity** of 10, and with **size** 0.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question after what you've added with your edit: No, there's no such method to fill a list with ascending integers in the standard collections API. You'll have to program a loop yourself and add elements to the list.